# No output when parsing textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, textarea

I have a text box that will have a large block of text pasted into it.

Then I parse the text into an array, removing whitespace. I need to pull the data out of certain array elements and put them into separate variables so I can generate a cleaner, formatted output.

The problem is that noting appears to be passed into my variables from the array. I've toyed with it a bit, and the array is being filled correctly, but the elements aren't passing strings to the variable.

HTML:

```
<p>Contact Name: <b id='contactNameOutput'></b></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function generateOutputfvoc() {
    var inputArr = document.getElementById('inputBox').value.split(/[\s]/);
    document.getElementById('contactNameOutput').innerHTML = inputArr[0];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific programming issue? We are not supposed to do merely a code lifting!

Comment: What doesn't work? It would be helpful if you created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and included the HTML in addition to the JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry... My output comes up with "Undefined". Apparently a value never gets passed through.

Comment: @Mrow The JSFiddle is for us...

Comment: +1 for JSFiddle. I'm a bit of a newbie...but I read the rules and did my homework. >.< Anyways, thank you all.

Comment: @Mrow change the title. Now it's a non-descriptive bulls*it. Specify input and expected output. Ask precise questions. No one's going to help you if you ask `Can anyone give me some advice on my code?` And by the way you're trying to access array elements with negative indexes.

Comment: About the way your code looks : you could start by following those excellent [guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone. I changed the title to be a little more descriptive.

Comment: Full edit in attempts to save this horrible post. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things going on here wich are hard to understand why you've done them.
My asumption is that `inputBox` is either a textarea or a input field into wich the user writes something.

Okay so you're splitting that string on whitespaces so for example the string

> The quick brown fox

would result in a array which looks like this:

```
inputArr = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
```

Now in your for-loop you're iterating over this array, starting at 0 and incrementing till you reach the end of the array, nothing strange here.

But in the first iteration, in the if-clause that you have, you're trying to access the array with negative values, remember `i` is `0`, this results in an undefined value, also in the last part of the if clause you're trying to access `i+1` well what happens when `i` is at its last value?! You guessed it another undefined! Later the loop will access old values which you've allready gone through, and honestly I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

All your if-statements are a mess really, especially if your gonna do them in that loop.
My guess is that you thought that you needed a for-loop for this, when in fact you do not.

What you have is one array containing the words in your textarea, if you know the order of what you're expecting, (can you really know what the user will put in that textarea?), then you can just access the words directly since you'll know the index of each item in the array. Otherwise, rewrite this to something simpler, always try to keep it simple.

Also why not look up `refactoring` while you're at it?!

**edit**

I think that the problem you have now is that the first element in the array is an empty string, that happens if there's a space in the beginning of the input.

Comment: Sigh. Well thank you for being blunt. I knew my code was sloppy to say they least, and I've been trying to learn ways of making my code more efficient, but I wasn't sure how to tackle this issue. I knew I needed to ask for help, but I was afraid of being treated like I haven't spent a lot of time on this. I've spent weeks! Anyways, I really appreciate your reply and the nudge in the right direction. I'll look into that. +1 if I could :(

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to sound harsh or belittling, but it is really hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. I think it's commendable that you're trying and always remember just because others doesn't understand your code, doesn't in any way mean that you're a moron, or alternatively it means that every programmer in the world is a moron. Because it's inherently tricky to understand other persons thoughts expressed in code.

Comment: Agreed. I think that's really part of my problem. I'm doing 90% of my learning on the internet looking at code that is way over my head. I need to go back to school...

Comment: Start with something easier then, there is value in finishing projects, but it sounds like what you're trying to do here is not helping you learn. Start fresh with something else, maybe do a subset of what you're trying to accomplish here instead. Then in the end you could put the pieces together and maybe have a working product.

Comment: Thank you again! Refactoring is exactly what I'm interested in, I just didn't really know what to call it. :) I love the idea of writing sloppy code and then going over it again, making it more efficient, until it's perfect. I think I have OCD. >.< Haha, anyways, I just really appreciated your posts today. If I ever get enough reputation I will give you +++ :)

Comment: No need to do that, my answer wasn't really good in regard to your actual question so it doesn't really deserve a +1, but I'm happy that I could help! :D

Comment: This post might be dormant now, but I have a quick, specific question about my code. I simplified things down as much as I could (yay refactoring!) Since I knew that there would be certain strings at certain locations in the array I could attempt to access them without going through the array with a for loop. I'm going to updated the entire post and put the code in there that I'm having problems with.